# Microsoft Power Apps Licence

Tags: office365, powerapps, power-automate, power-platform

What is the difference between the Power Apps that comes with A5 Licence (which I have) and P2 licence a friend of mine has for development? What capabilities will the A5 licence miss compared to to the Plan 2?

Answer (score 0):

This has multiple different dimensions and Microsoft keeps on changing plans/licensing models/features. It’s a moving target, in simple words.

One thing to call out is Education vs Enterprise (commercial).

[P1/P2 Plans retiring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/powerapps-flow-licensing-faq#what-will-happen-to-the-power-apps-p1p2-and-power-automate-plan-1-and-plan-2-plans-on-october-1-2019)

> **What will happen to the Power Apps P1/P2 and Power Automate Plan 1 and Plan 2 plans on October 1, 2019?**
> The existing P1 and P2 plans for Power Apps and Power Automate will be transitioning to the new Power Apps per app and per user plans, as well as the Power Automate per user and per Power Automate plans. Existing customers will be able to maintain the P1 and P2 plans for Power Apps and Power Automate for the duration of their current subscription period, and they may be eligible to also renew under current terms depending upon when their subscription period expires. Similarly, new customers may be able to purchase the existing P1 and P2 plans prior to April 1, 2020. Please contact your Microsoft account rep for more information.

Though this [MVP blog](https://thatapiguy.tech/2019/04/07/powerapps-and-flow-license-based-on-office-365-license/) explains that A5 will get Power platform capabilities, Microsoft 365 & Office 365 [Education plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-365-platform-service-description/microsoft-365-education) not talking about any Power platform capabilities, so better consult with some MS account reps to get clarity.